# ExtJS 5.1 -- My Store is empty, but emptyText is not appearing?

Tags: javascript, extjs, django-rest-framework

I have read quite a few articles and posts and everything I've tried has not worked. I am using ExtJS 5.1.

**Handler bound to `change` event:**

```
'combobox': {
    change: 'onComboboxChange'  // filter when box value is changed
}
```

**Here is the `change` handler:**

```
onComboboxChange: function (combobox, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
    var store = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
    store.removeFilter('myFilter');
    if (newValue !== 'All') {
        store.addFilter({
            id: 'myFilter',
            filterFn: function (record) {
                return record.get('status').toLowerCase() === newValue.toLowerCase();
            }
        });
    } // AT THIS POINT IN THE FUNCTION store.getCount() === 0
}
```

**Question:** When I click an option in the combo box that yields no results in the store, the empty text does not show. It used to work when I had another combo box, so something must be wrong with this. I even step through with debugger and check to make sure the actual count is 0, and it is, and the empty text still does now show.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`deferEmptyText: false`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-deferEmptyText):

> True to defer `emptyText` being applied until the store's first load.

This needs to set on the [`listConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-listConfig):

> An optional set of configuration properties that will be passed to the `Ext.view.BoundList`'s constructor. Any configuration that is valid for BoundList can be included.

For example:

```
listConfig: {
  deferEmptyText: false
}
```